# Cannot place SwiftUI view outside the SafeArea when embedded in UIHostingController

Tags: swiftui, uikit, safearealayoutguide, uihostingcontroller

I have a simple SwiftUI view that contains 3 text elements:

```
struct ImageDescriptionView: View {
    var title: String?
    var imageDescription: String?
    var copyright: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        
            if let title = title {
                Text(title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        
            if let imageDescription = imageDescription {
                Text(imageDescription)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        
            if let copyright = copyright {
                Text(copyright)
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        
        }
        .background(
            Color.blue
        )
    }
}
```

The SwiftUI View is embedded within a `UIHostingController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: ImageDescriptionView(title: "25. November 2021", imageDescription: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", copyright: "Bild © Unknown"))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpHC()
    }

    private func setUpHC() {
        hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .red
    
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        addChild(hostingController)
        hostingController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

}
```

#### The result looks like this:

[image]

The UIHostingController is always bigger than the view. Also, it will always make the SwiftUI view respect the safe area (which in my case, I do not want)

#### The look I want:

(please don't comment the usability of the home indicator, that's not the case here)

[image]

What's the problem with UIHostingController? I tried setting .edgesIgnoreSafeArea(.all) on all Views within `ImageDescriptionView`, did not help.

Comment: I've seen this question pop up a few times this last week, and honestly it seems to be the one question that's not getting answers.

Comment: I just ran your code on Xcode 14 attached to an iPhone 13 pro simulator running both iOS 15.5 and iOS 16. Turns out they fixed it in the new OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex mentioned in a comment to my question, it seems like Apple fixed it.

### Xcode 14.3, iOS 16 Simulator

[image]

Answer (score 12):

On the UIHostingControllers property try the following

```swift
viewController._disableSafeArea = true
```

that should do the trick.

Comment: Since it's a private API, anyone tested for a AppStore release?

Comment: This works for me, did someone have the uploaded to the Appstore?

Answer (score 10):

### iOS 16.4 Update

There's now an official API in iOS 16.4 for the previously private API method:

```
viewController.safeAreaRegions = SafeAreaRegions()
```

The `SafeAreaRegions()` initialiser returns an empty collection. Default value of `.safeAreaRegions` is `.all`.

### Backwards compatible answer

If you want to be backwards compatible and support iOS 13+, there is a workaround:

```
let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: buttonView)
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
let inverseSafeAreaInset = window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
controller.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -inverseSafeAreaInset, right: 0)
```

Note you can get the inverse offset from the parent view / VC in multiple ways. e.g. `view.safeAreaInsets` works once the view has been laid out, however the `window` approach works for all contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Got [a discussion here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OJFZJQ1bJbwJ:https://twitter.com/b3ll/status/1193747288302075906%3Flang%3Den%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), and [the detail here](https://defagos.github.io/swiftui_collection_part3/)

```
extension UIHostingController {
    convenience public init(rootView: Content, ignoreSafeArea: Bool) {
        self.init(rootView: rootView)
        
        if ignoreSafeArea {
            disableSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    func disableSafeArea() {
        guard let viewClass = object_getClass(view) else { return }
        
        let viewSubclassName = String(cString: class_getName(viewClass)).appending("_IgnoreSafeArea")
        if let viewSubclass = NSClassFromString(viewSubclassName) {
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
        else {
            guard let viewClassNameUtf8 = (viewSubclassName as NSString).utf8String else { return }
            guard let viewSubclass = objc_allocateClassPair(viewClass, viewClassNameUtf8, 0) else { return }
            
            if let method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(getter: UIView.safeAreaInsets)) {
                let safeAreaInsets: @convention(block) (AnyObject) -> UIEdgeInsets = { _ in
                    return .zero
                }
                class_addMethod(viewSubclass, #selector(getter: UIView.safeAreaInsets), imp_implementationWithBlock(safeAreaInsets), method_getTypeEncoding(method))
            }
            
            objc_registerClassPair(viewSubclass)
            object_setClass(view, viewSubclass)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue. You have to ignore the safe area at the SwiftUI view level.

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        ...
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all) // ignore all safe area insets
}
```

Comment: it does not give the same result as the solutions above. The part of the view that occupies the safearea becomes invisible/invisible while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too. When I aligned my view with the frame it worked, but to make it work with autolayout I had to consider the height of the safe area to make it work with UIHostingController, even though I didn't have to do that with a standard view.

code:

```
hostingVC.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: view.safeAreaInsets.bottom).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a circle view inside UIHostingController and its background automatically resized when it close to safe area. I could be able to avoid it by setting autoresizesSubviews to false.

```
UIHostingController.view.autoresizesSubview = false
```